# Pycharm console crashes after starting JVM with jpype

Tags: python, jvm, pycharm

So basically I was trying to use some java pacakage in python using jpype with pycharm.

After I set up the environmental variable `JAVA_HOME` I started JVM using this code

```
from jpype import *
startJVM(getDefaultJVMPath())
```

It's all good until I start to test on the functionality with this

```
java.lang.System.out.println('hello world')
```

I didn't even get to finish the line of code before this error popped out

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

This error pops as soon as I finish `java.lang`

I am using win10 and the environmental variables has been setup correctly